# Use tryCatch or other handling for callAPI error in Rfacebook

Tags: r, facebook, error-handling, try-catch

I have a list of facebook user names that might contain errors.  I want to call getUsers on the lot of them and get how many likes each one has.  If getUsers encounters a bad user name, I want to remove it from the list and try again.

I want to do this in Rfacebook (but if the answer is that I must use httr and write the GET requests myself, so be it).

```
load("fbCred.RData") # you will need a Facebook credential to execute this

library(Rfacebook)

fb_users <- c("brucespringsteen","coldplay")
fb_likes <- tryCatch(getUsers(users=fb_users,token=fbCred)$likes)
fb_likes # Returns: [1]  4807200 36768913

fb_users <- c("brucespringsteen","coldplay","This-Bad-Name-Will-Fail")
fb_likes <- tryCatch(getUsers(users=fb_users,token=fbCred)$likes)
# Returns:
# Error in callAPI(query, token) : 
#   (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: This-Bad-Name-Will-Fail
if(inherits(fb_likes,"error")){
  # I want to remove the one that failed from the list of users and try again. 
  # But the callAPI error never makes it into fb_likes. 
}
```

Is there a way to do it in Rfacebook?  How do I retrieve the name of the bad user so that I can remove it from the list and retry?

EDIT:  I know I can loop through the user names one by one.  That is my current workaround (using adply) but takes much much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is of class "try-error", not "error".  Also, you need to use `try`, not `tryCatch`:

```
fb_likes <- try(getUsers(users=fb_users,token=fbCred)$likes)
if(inherits(fb_likes, "try-error")) { ... }
```

should work.  `tryCatch` is more complex and requires a different structure, something like:

```
tryCatch(
  fb_likes <- getUsers(users=fb_users,token=fbCred)$likes,
  error=function(e) { 
    err.msg <- conditionMessage(e)
    ...
} )
```

Comment: Thanks BrodieG.  I have put the correct code as a supplementary answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
load("fbCred.RData") # you will need a Facebook credential to execute this

library(Rfacebook)

fb_users <- c("brucespringsteen","coldplay","This_Will_Fail","Bad_Bad_Bad")

fb_likes <- try(getUsers(users=fb_users,token=fbCred)$likes)

if(inherits(fb_likes,"try-error")){
  bad_users <- unlist(strsplit(sub(".*exist\\:\\s+(.*)\\n$","\\1",
                           fb_likes[1]),split=","))
  print(paste("These user names failed, removing:", 
          paste(bad_users,collapse=", ")))
  fb_users <- setdiff(fb_users,bad_users)
  fb_likes <- getUsers(users=fb_users,token=fbCred)$likes
}
print(data.frame(fb_users,fb_likes))
```

Produces the desired output:

```
[1] "These user names failed, removing: This_Will_Fail, Bad_Bad_Bad"

          fb_users fb_likes
1 brucespringsteen  4808496
2         coldplay 36786558
```

To extract the list of bad users (using a regex and strsplit) one can start from `geterrmessage()` (assuming it's the last error) but it's probably more reliable to start from the `try-error` object itself.  Then I use `setdiff` to remove the bad users.

Comment: When you call over a hundred or so usernames, the likes counts start coming back in a different order than the usernames in the array.  So you have to use the username column from the data frame returned by getUsers, not the original fb_users column.